# Can't substring in Django template tag

Tags: django

I am trying to add a trailing 's' to a string unless the string's last character is an 's'. How do I do this in a Django template? The [-1] below is causing an error:

```
{{ name }}{% if name[-1] != "s" %}s{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% if name|slice:"-1:"|first != "s" %}s{% endif %}
```

Django's slice filter doesn't handle colon-less slices correctly so the slice:"-1" solution does not work.  Leveraging the |first filter in addition, seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

try the [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice) filter

```
{% if name|slice:"-1" != "s" %}
```

Comment: I tried your snippet exactly. The name I used was "Thomas" and the left side of the comparison expression evaluated to "Thoma" not "s".

Comment: Should be just "-1" (without the second colon).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried your suggestion as {{ name.slice:"-1" }} but again this evaluated to "Danie" not "l" (for example). I am running Python 2.5.2. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> The Django template system provides tags which function similarly to some programming constructs – an if tag for boolean tests, a for
>   tag for looping, etc. – but these are not simply executed as the
>   corresponding Python code, and the template system will not execute
>   arbitrary Python expressions.

Use the [slice built-in filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but django has a built-in template filter that pluralizes words. It's called just that: pluralize.
You'd want something like this:

```
{{name | pluralize}}
```

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Doesn't apply to the question.  But it is useful for cases when you're pluralizing the display of a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

`{% if name|last != "s" %}` does the job